# How to make the result from a request factory call available for for injection using GIN?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, gwt-gin

I have a proxy, let's call it ConfigParametersProxy.

It has a method (for example) String getParameter1();

It is a request factory managed value proxy.

I want to be able to do this with it in my java/gwt code...

@Inject
ConfigParameterProxy parameters;

How do I set this up so this works?

I am using GIN, so have a client module etc.

Comment: Have you tried using GIN (https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) or Errai (http://erraiframework.org/) ?

Comment: hmmm... should have mentioned  that, I am using gin - updated question